# Error while connecting to kafka with Apache flink Batch mode

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am trying to consume messages from a Kafka topic in Apache flink running in Batch mode.
Below is the code snippet using "KafkaSource"

```
env.setRuntimeMode(RuntimeExecutionMode.BATCH);

KafkaSource<String> source = KafkaSource.<String>builder()
                    .setBounded(OffsetsInitializer.committedOffsets(OffsetResetStrategy.EARLIEST))
                    .setBootstrapServers(<kafka server address>)
                    .setTopics("abcd.a1")
                    .setGroupId("my-group")
                    .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
                    .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new SimpleStringSchema())
                    .build();

DataStreamSource<String> dataStream = env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "Kafka Source");
                dataStream.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, Tuple3<String, String, String>>() {

                    @Override
                    public void flatMap(String value, Collector<Tuple3<String, String, String>> out) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println("Consumed message "+value);
                        
                    }
                });
```

When I try above, getting below error always,

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Partition abcd.a1-2 should stop at committed offset. But there is no committed offset of this partition for group my-group
        at org.apache.flink.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:76)
        at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.KafkaPartitionSplitReader.lambda$acquireAndSetStoppingOffsets$3(KafkaPartitionSplitReader.java:360)
        at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1288)
        at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.KafkaPartitionSplitReader.acquireAndSetStoppingOffsets(KafkaPartitionSplitReader.java:358)
        at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.KafkaPartitionSplitReader.handleSplitsChanges(KafkaPartitionSplitReader.java:257)
        at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.fetcher.AddSplitsTask.run(AddSplitsTask.java:51)
        at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.fetcher.SplitFetcher.runOnce(SplitFetcher.java:142)
```

I have tried with both "OffsetsInitializer.earliest()" and "OffsetsInitializer.latest()".
Please help me on that. Let me know if its duplicate post, will close it.
Thank you

Comment: What's the value set for `enable.auto.commit` configuration?

Comment: I have nt set it in flink job. FYI, When I run the flink job in Stream mode, no errors and able to consume messages with the code mentioned.